# Lazy query response after Indexing views - CouchDB on Android Device

Tags: android, nosql, view, couchdb, ektorp

I am using **CouchDB** in my **Android** application. *My app also syncs data to an online server.* The problem that I am facing with the CouchDB views is that when I call a view it takes a lot of time to return the resulted documents(even when `includeDocs(false)`). It should cache the view for the first time so that retrieval will be fast for other times in the future.

If I run the view on the server side then **data is cached automatically** but calling those views from Android device causes delay in response. In this case when data is synced on my Android device, these views should fetch the data  from **localhost** rather than online - so retrieval should be fast from **localhost** but it is not.

Might be indices of localhost(Android device) couchdb are not indexed that is why everytime I call a view it returns the result after a lot of delay. Any Idea how to resolve this issue.

::*I am using Ektorp API for couchdb.*

Comment: It's hard to tell for sure, but it sounds like you are using a temporary view instead of having it saved as a design document. Might it be the case?

Comment: I am saving the view to Local couch in Android tab, so what might be the reason that views are not being updated?  Most probably they are not because if I write a new View in my program then it does not update in design document.

Comment: Exactly, so this is where I think you problem lies. Your design document(s) should define all the views your application uses, and they shouldn't be modified. Every time you do modify them, couchdb needs to rebuild the view index from scratch, and this has to take a lot.

Comment: Actually, I have a check in the code, if the view is changed only then view is indexed otherwise it does not do anything with the views in design docs.

Comment: What do I need to index views on Android Device?

Comment: Can you update the question with the pieces of the code you mentioned?

Comment: I have tested Views creation and updation.

I create "viewName": "JavaScript Query" in the design documents programmatically but the view is updated every time I change "JavaScript query" in the program otherwise it does not.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you are misusing the views. These are not adhoc queries you build up during your program runtime like you would build up an SQL query. Rather than that try thinking about them as database indexes, the part of your schema. The design document(s) should only be updated when you release a new version of your application in the live environment.

Try to organize your schema thinking about the ways you need to retrieve the data. In the end your program finite number of types of queries. You should prepare the indexes upfront and than only query them during the application runtime.

Comment: Actually, my code of creating Views is working fine. It only creates the Views only once and the design documents are then set to rev-1-rev_id.

So there is not issue with the Views updation or something. View are not being updated on every run of application. They are created once, then no updates are given to them and they remain at rev-1.

Comment: I am awarding you this bounty for your helpful efforts but my question is still unanswered in a way.

Comment: Hmm, I must have misunderstood this part of your comment "but the view is updated every time I change "JavaScript query"". Can you show me the code doing this ?

Comment: I just said that I have a code with 2D array in which

String[][] MapFunctions = {{View_Name1, Query1}, {View_Name2, Query2}};

I create views through this code, connecting it with the logic which checks if any Query1 or Query2 have been modified. If modified then the corresponding view will be updated with the modified query. otherwise not.